# StandardScaler on list with matrix as list element

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, scaling

I have a List with patients. Each patient has a (n x m) matrix with values.

[image]

Now I want to normalize the data over all patients with mean/std using the StandardScaler.

The problem is that it apparently cannot include several list entries.

is there a possibility do use this command or do I need to do it by hand with a for loop?

Cheers

p.s.:
I get

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is due to the matrix sizes while StandardScaler is supposedly only working with arrays.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example?

Comment: If the function does not support multiple lists as parameter, you could use list-comprehensions. What is your function call?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I added a picture of the matrix for better understanding. Yes, one idea was to merge all values, then do the StandardScaler and separate the values again by the length of the original List. But I hoped for a  better solution by making the StandardScaler useful for multiple lists. The function call is: StandardScaler().fit(PatientData);StandardScaler.transform(PatientData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an array of patient data matrices like this:

```
my_patient_data_X
```

Then you can do this:

```
my_patient_data_X = [StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) for X in my_patient_data_X]
```

Would this achieve what you want?

Comment: wow, that was easy. Thanks a lot. I will need more time with python for that to come naturally to me. Have a nice day.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Comment: @Ohumeronen this will not standardise the matrices together. It merely standardises each patients matrix by itself. OP wanted over all patients.